# how to fire event on label text change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to fire a function when the label text changes. This is my code

```
$("#frameItemCode").change(function (e) {
    alert("Changed");
});
```

`#frameItemCode` is my label id, but the event isn't firing. I have tried examples given before but they hasn't helped me.This is my html

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" @*style="width: 120px;"*@>Item Group</span>
  <label class="input-group-addon" @*style="width: 120px;"*@ id="frameGroupCode"></label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="frameGroupName" style="">
</div>
```

Comment: you mean input textbox ?

Comment: Can you give us the html code?

Comment: How do you change the label text?

Comment: @SarangaSachinthana: A normal HTML label isn't editable so this is slightly confusing. Adding the HTML would help us figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Non-form elements do not trigger a `change` event. You should look into [Mutation Obeservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: you can use onblur event `onblur="javascript:alert('change occurred')"` as @Lix suggested

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation for the `change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change). It only fires for specific types of elements:

> The change event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the user...

You won't be able to use the `change` event for an element that is not one of the previously mentioned types.

If you have some other way of knowing that editing has finished of a specific element, you'll have to fire your own event - possibly using the [`blur` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) on the element that was used to change the value. The `blur` event is triggered when the selected element looses focus such as when a user clicks (or tabs) out of an input element.

Answer (score 5):

For label **`.change()`** will not work, So you can try something like this by using **`trigger()`** which call our custom event, here  `fnLabelChanged` is my custom event

`.change()`  event worked for `<input>` , `<textarea>` ,`<select>` .i.e

```
$("button").on('click',function(){
         $("#frameGroupCode").text("Hello").trigger("fnLabelChanged");
    });


    $("#frameGroupCode").on('fnLabelChanged', function(){
        console.log('changed');
    })
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7srfn3a4/3/)**

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current text of the label and check if the value is different on keyup or when pressing a button. The `change` event doesn't work for non form elements.

Comment: by using $("#frameItemCode").text('abc')

Comment: This would be a good idea, but "listening" for a keyup event should only occur when you know that the user is currently in the element that changes the text. It would be best to turn off that listener when the user is elsewhere on the page or has focus on an unrelated element.

Answer (score 2):

If you use, `$("#frameItemCode").text('abc')` to change the lable (as you commented), just call the `alert("changed")` after that. No need to define an event listener..

```
$("#frameItemCode").text('abc');
alert("changed");
```

---

If the label changes in several ways, define a timeInterval to check if the label has changed,

```
function inspectLabel(callback){
    var label = $("#frameItemCode").text();
    setInterval(function(){
        var newlabel = $("#frameItemCode").text();
        if (newlabel != label){
            callback();
            label = newlabel;
        }
    }, 100);
}

inspectLabel(function(){
    alert('changed');
});
```

Comment: no i have assign values to that label in several times using several conditions. because of that i need to use that type of method.

Comment: thats not what i want

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which browsers you need to support, you can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(
    function (mutations) {
        alert('Label was changed!');
    }
);

observer.observe(document.querySelector('#frameGroupCode'), { childList: true });
```

Example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xht4aufo/)

Comment: so MutationObserver is easy

Answer (score 0):

I don't think label has change() event associated with it, if you want to achive it, then it can be done through JQuery or JS. Because changing label text dynamically is done through Jquery or JS.

Instead, you can create a function and call it when the label is being changed from your function where the lable text change takes place.

Comment: also think about that, but i thought there was another better way to do that. thats why i ask this question.