# Detect Label Change Using - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lookup field so based on the drop down change the lookup field value changes

```js
var name;
$("#tdf_15").on('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
   name =  $(this).html();
   alert(name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tdf_15" class="cell dc" style="background-color: rgb(255, 253, 221);">Dileep Thomas</div>
```

So this snippet will alert whenever the lookup field changes , but the alert is working for three times initially when the field is blank and once it is have a value then alert will work for four times at each time we change the drop down. I need to have the alert for only one time also i need to check the value in the variable(**name**) is changed or not.

Many thanks in advance if anyone can help me !!

Comment: Html please.BTW i am unable to understand your question fully. can you add html so that we can check and get better understanding?

Comment: Thanks Samuel. I think right now you can check the question ?

Comment: you div doesn't have anything. And what is your desired outcome?

Comment: the div will have dynamic values. It is based on a drop down field. I know you will suggest me to have "function on(change)" on the drop down field, but  the drop down is having browse choices and a record picker. As i am not an expert i tried in this manner. Is there any solution

Comment: Is there any way to solve this issue ??

Answer (score 1):

Change `DOMSubtreeModified` to `change`

```
var name;
$("#tdf_15").on('change', function () {
   name =  $(this).html();
   alert(name);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, when i checked on the documentation and some articles on ('change') will work for the input elements and some fields not the labels, So in order to know the change on the DOM i used "DOMSubtreeModified". Is there any way i can solve the issue !!

Answer (score 1):

I think i got the solution i searched the developers google Stackoverflow itself

The below link 4th  answer solved this isssue

[how to fire event on label text change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635600/how-to-fire-event-on-label-text-change)